# Select only works on <select> elements, not on <option>

Tags: css

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="row search-table-setting">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2" />
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 pull-right">
      <div class="form-select ">
        <label>
          <select class="selectpicker classReset ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid bs-select-hidden" ng-change="SetPageSize()" ng-model="recordPerPage">
            <option value="">10 Per Page</option>
            <option value="20">20 Per Page</option>
            <option value="30">30 Per Page</option>
            <option value="40">40 Per Page</option>
            <option value="50">50 Per Page</option>
          </select>
```

In above code when I am trying to select the values using python web-driver, but getting the error

> selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on  elements, not on

Please help me how can I resolve this.

Comment: r u using some js function

Answer (score 0):

ng-change="SetPageSize()" ng-model="recordPerPage"
 remove this and try